# Installing Laravel Backpack 4.1 into Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I am trying to install Backpack 4.1 into Laravel 8. I ran

```
composer require backpack/crud:"4.1.*"
```

But I received the following error.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
> backpack/crud[4.1.22, ..., 4.1.x-dev] require doctrine/dbal ^2.5 -> found doctrine/dbal[v2.5.0-BETA2, ..., 2.12.x-dev] but it conflicts
> with your root composer.json require (^3.0).
> backpack/crud[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.21] require laravel/framework ^7.0|^6.0 -> found laravel/framework[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0,
> ..., 7.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require
> (^8.12).
> Root composer.json requires backpack/crud 4.1.* -> satisfiable by backpack/crud[4.1.0, ..., 4.1.x-dev].

I have been looking around but have not found a solution yet. Versions: Laravel 8.17, PHP 7.3.24

**UPDATE** I have tried installing 4.2; please see below.

> Root composer.json requires backpack/crud 4.2.* -> satisfiable by
> backpack/crud[4.2.x-dev]. backpack/crud 4.2.x-dev requires
> doctrine/dbal ^2.5 -> found doctrine/dbal[v2.5.0-BETA2, ...,
> 2.12.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see anything about 4.2 in the docs I will give it a go now.

Comment: Just tried 4.2 please see my update

Comment: I have had a look at 4.2 `compser.json` and it still is `doctrine/dbal 2.5` so looks like its not Laravel 8 ready?

Comment: I was just thinking the same. I'm having a look now.

Comment: I have just removed doctrine (could not see witch package was using it) and installed backpack fine. Thanks. If you add this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Can you please retract my accepted answer so I can delete it? Backpack4.1 now seems to be available for Laravel8. Thx. I'll also remove all of my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending answer removal.
It seems Backpack 4.1 now supports Laravel8

Comment: I don't think that's it... there is no Backpack 4.2. I mean there will be, but it's currently WIP, unavailable to install and has no docs. The latest version is Backpack 4.1.

Comment: That being said, what you were looking at was the 4.1 BRANCH. Which was out of date. Normally we work on feature branches and merge to MASTER, not to the 4.1 BRANCH. I've just merged everything in MASTER into 4.1, just in case the OP was trying to install the branch, and not the version.